# How to export selenium results to qTest

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, qtestlib

Instead of running and publishing results selenium tests from qTest, I want to execute selenium tests from local or other PC and publish the results into qTest.
Do we have an API available or any process to export the results to qTest?

Thanks!